# Android ArrayList, how to get onClick of ListView

Tags: java, android, api, arraylist, foursquare

I was testing the sample code from [foursquare-api](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-foursquare-api-example/)

What I would like to know, How can I get the onClick item for the list view ?

so after the get the list of venue, If the user click on the list item, I want to send the avenue name to another fragment to handle it.

thanks

**Java Coding**

```
ArrayList<FoursquareVenue> venuesList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

private static ArrayList<FoursquareVenue> parseFoursquare(final String response) {

ArrayList<FoursquareVenue> temp = new ArrayList<FoursquareVenue>();
try {

    // make an jsonObject in order to parse the response
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

    // make an jsonObject in order to parse the response
    if (jsonObject.has("response")) {
        if (jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").has("venues")) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("venues");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                FoursquareVenue poi = new FoursquareVenue();
                if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("name")) {
                    poi.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));

                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("location")) {
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").has("address")) {
                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").has("city")) {
                                poi.setCity(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("city"));
                            }
                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("categories")) {
                                if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").length() > 0) {
                                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").getJSONObject(0).has("icon")) {
                                        poi.setCategory(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            temp.add(poi);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return new ArrayList<FoursquareVenue>();
}
return temp;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (temp == null) {
        // we have an error to the call
        // we can also stop the progress bar
    } else {
        // all things went right

        // parseFoursquare venues search result
        venuesList = (ArrayList<FoursquareVenue>) parseFoursquare(temp);

        List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < venuesList.size(); i++) {
            // make a list of the venus that are loaded in the list.
            // show the name, the category and the city
            listTitle.add(i, venuesList.get(i).getName() + ", " + venuesList.get(i).getCategory() + "" + venuesList.get(i).getCity());
        }

        // set the results to the list
        // and show them in the xml
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LocationActivity.this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, listTitle);
        setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

---

Thanks

I have tried this :

```
 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "position => " + position + 
             " - ListView =>" + l + 
             " - View => " + v +
             " - id => " + id
             , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

I can get the position of the listView Item, But I can not the the data of the list view.

I am also using this:

```
public class FoursquareVenue {
    private String name;
    private String city;

    private String category;

    public FoursquareVenue() {
        this.name = "";
        this.city = "";
        this.setCategory("");
    }

    public String getCity() {
        if (city.length() > 0) {
            return city;
        }
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        if (city != null) {
            this.city = city.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");
            ;
        }
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
```

Comment: Those nested if's with `getJSONObject` in them look bad. i hope that method is not called a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just override

```
onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

which is called when an item in the list is selected. Since, you are invoking `setListAdapter()` I'm assuming you've extended either `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`.

To retrieve the `ListView` data use `ListView#getItemAtPosition()` method.

Now, here's where you would realise that using an `ArrayAdapter<FoursquareVenue>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>` would have been better because with the `String` version, all you would be able to retrieve with `getItemAtPosition()`, is exactly the same string that you passed at

```
listTitle.add(i, venuesList.get(i).getName() + ", " +
    venuesList.get(i).getCategory() + "" + venuesList.get(i).getCity());
```

which is clearly not very flexible. You should pass your `venuesList` directly to the adapter as

```
myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoursquareVenue>(
    LocationActivity.this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, venuesList);
```

and then override `FoursquareVenue#toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder(name).append(", ")
           .append(category).append(", ").append(city).toString();
}
```

Comment: Hello Ravi Thapliyal, thanks .
I try it. I can get the position of the listView Item, But I can not the the data of the list view. I have edited my question.

Comment: Use `ListView#getItemAtPosition()` to retrieve the list item.

Answer (score 1):

init  your listview from main.xml

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and add

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

}
```

Comment: Requires the `Activity`/`Fragment` to unnecessarily implement an Interface. Not to mention casting the `AdapterView` as well. Both of these can be avoided.

Comment: I am using a - public class LocationActivity extends ListActivity implements LocationListener {  - I am not calling listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);. Thanks for ur feedback